# Storage variable vs CustomName

Tags: space-engineers

I'm looking to persist data from a script.

What are the pros and cons of both for persisting data?
Is there any difference at all?

From [the docs](http://spaceengineerswiki.com/Programming_Guide) it says that:

> The Storage variable is unique in that that it store data as string between saved seasons and recompile.

That seems the same to me for storage purposes. Am I right in saying that CustomName is tied to any block and is visible to other blocks while Storage is private to its programmable block?

Comment: I don't know Space Engineers, but this sounds more like a programming question rather than a "space engineer" one.

Comment: No it's specifically asking about the interface within the game, it's not a generic programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Storage is a variable only accessible by your script where as CustomName can be changed in the user interface. Both survive for the life time of the block but I would recommend using CustomName only for printing outputs to the heads up display.